# Prevent user from setting id of JPA/Hibernate Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

How do I prevent someone from creating an entity and setting it's id? I want to defer to the database autoincrement and make it throw a 409 error if it happens. I am trying @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) with the primary key in the database autoincrementing, but the setting of the id is never flagged as a problem and will override my autoincrement scheme in the mysql database.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is : make your `id property and its setter method private`, which will not let user access `setId` method of your object,

But as Hibernate uses set method to initialize the entity which you're reading from your DB, it can access this method using reflection. So you don't have to worry about changing any other things.

Comment: Thanks Vimal. I am trying to recreate a 409 error for unit testing. Is there ever a case where setting the id to a value and creating the entity will trigger this? I have read that this can trigger a 409 error, but I can't seem to make it happen?

Comment: I was hoping that there was a configuration of @GeneratedValue that might do this, but AUTO and IDENTITY seem to allow setting of id on the entity . I get a 400 when I restrict access to the setting of id  with a private setter or removing the setter entirely.

Comment: sorry, I don't think this is a very good question. I apologize.

Comment: That's ok @JohnStafford. But I'm not aware about how to trigger 409 on accessing setter.

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you can only have a getter on the id, but i do not know hibernate/jpa

Comment: yeah, that probably would work, but I was hoping for a configuration of Hibernate

Comment: Works for me when using '@GeneratedValue ' for '@Id's (Hibernate, JPA, field access)